# FTP Account created on Windows Server 2016. Cannot connect from my local computer

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2016

First of all, I am sorry if this question is not supposed to be posted here. I have created an FTP account in a server running Windows Server 2016. I have remote access to this server and have full control. Below are the steps that I followed to create the FTP

Created a fresh FTP site in IIS

Physical path: `c:\xampp\htdocs\yd`

Added a new user. Username: iamuser-wp. Password: ****** All required
permissions are set Staying on the server, I am able to login to this FTP account like this:

```
ftp://127.0.0.1
Username: iamuser-wp
Password: *******
```

But when I am trying to connect it using the server's IP address with the same credential, i.e.

```
ftp://142.x.x.x
Username: iamuser-wp
Password: *******
```

I cannot log in.

It was evident, still I tried the same combination from my local machine

```
ftp://142.x.x.x
Username: iamuser-wp
Password: *******
```

and as expected, I could not connect.

In IIS, The user isolation is set to Root Directory because I selected the directory where YD files resides

Basic Authentication: `Enabled`

FTP Authorization Rule:  `Mode > Allow. User > iamuser-wp. Permission > Read, Write`

FTP-SSL Setting: I did not make any change here. Don't know about it.

I don't know whether the IP address needs to be made accessible publicly.
What is the correct procedure to make this FTP account accessible via FTP clients from from my local machine? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try to connect?

Comment: No visible error is coming up. It is trying to connect and then gets back to the dialogue box without any message.

Comment: Well, then try a different FTP client that provides a helpful error message. Windows 10 still comes with the good old command line FTP client.

Comment: Can you please suggest a good one? I haven't used any so-called FTP client yet to connect. I am only trying from a browser by typing in like `ftp://142.x.x.x`.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is NATed, probably behind a firewall, the FTP server needs to be informed of the public IP, to allow passive mode connections. So, on IIS Manager, open FTP -> FTP Firewall Support and insert your server’s public IP address.

Also check these two:

- Is your public IP 142.x.x.x accessible, even from the local machine? It could be NATed through a firewall. Do you have any other service on the server that listens on a port on 142.x.x.x IP to try to connect?
- Have you checked site bindings on the IIS? Your FTP site could be bound to 127.0.0.1 only. If you don't know how to view binds in graphical interface of IIS, you can do it also by issuing this command:
  `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list sites`